# problem when writing an equation with latex: missing delimiter (. inserted) \end{equation}

Tags: equations

I tried this and that, but could not solve this problem. Here is the code that produces this error:

```
\begin{equation}
o=g(h)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
    1 & if & h <   0 \\
    0 & if & h \le 0 
\end{array}\right
\end{equation}
```

The error is given on the line `\end{equation}` resides.
Thanks.

Comment: Put a `.` after `\right` like `\right.`

Comment: Yes, this solved. But why the "."?

Comment: \right requires a following token to say what delimiter to stretch, or `.` to specify a null delimiter.  But your setting is wrong `if` is a multi letter word so should not be using the math italic font use `\mathrm{if}` or (much) better  use the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: BTW, if *h* < 0, then *g(h)* has two values 1 and 0? And *g(h)* is undefined for *h* > 0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\left\{` must be balanced by a `\right\}` in the same line. Since you don't want the right delimiter, and since the closing pair is needed, you have to put a null delimiter by `\right.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    o=g(h)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
                     1 & if & h <   0 \\
                     0 & if & h \le 0
\end{array}\right.  %% <--here
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But for this `amsmath` provides `cases` environment. I suggest you to use this. A sample will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    o=g(h)=\begin{cases}
              1 & \text{if $ h < 0 $}\\
              0 & \text{if $ h \le 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the use of `\text` macro which is also provided by `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{numcases}{|x|=} 
x, & for $x \geq 0$ \label{eq:4}
\\ -x, & for$x < 0$ \label{eq:5} 
\end{numcases}
```

You have to use

```
\usepackage{cases}
```